# Subspaces and submodules of $k[x,y]$

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces, modules, involutions

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero, $\beta$ an involution on $k[x,y]$
(a $k$-algebra automorphism of $k[x,y]$ of order two),
and $U \subseteq k[x,y]$ an ideal of $k[x,y]$ (a $k[x,y]$-submodule of $k[x,y]$).

> Does $\beta(U) \subseteq U$ imply something interesting about $U$?

Examples for 'interesting':
**(i)** $\dim(U) < \infty$ ($\dim$ may refer to any relevant dimension). **(ii)** There exists a generating set for $U$ as a $k[x,y]$-module consisting of 'pure' elements (pure = symmetric or skew-symmetric).

See also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_subspace).

**Edit:** More specifically, I am interested in a two generated ideal $U=\langle p,q \rangle$. Hopefully, considering such $U$ as a $k$-subspace or a $k[x,y]$-module may yield something interesting.

Any comments and hint are welcome!